# How to record audio in Android when headset is connected?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, record, microphone

I have a problem with recording in an Android application based in Android studio.

I need to record audio in Android but when I use headset my application cant record played sound, and when user decrease volume to 0 my app cant record played voice.

In my app I use headset, I play a media player and need to record mediaplayer output sound and microphone to a single file.

When headset is connected, my app can't record mediaplayer sound.

Please help me and give me a method for record audio played from device when headset is connected.

Comment: Not sure what your question is? Have you tried anything? Show us some code snippets.

Comment: any suggestion? I got this problem too